# Select and count simultaneously within a query of one table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to query a table and get one column of results then how many results there are for that column.  Currently I have to run two queries separately, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_a
FROM table_a
WHERE property_a = 1
AND property_b = 2;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_a)
FROM table_a
WHERE property_a = 1
AND property_b = 2;
```

I would rather combine these, since they are performing the same query, but I can't figure out how.  Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_a) AS my_count, DISTINCT field_a AS my_records
FROM table_a...
```

(I tried the GROUP BY, but that lists how many of each distinct result there are.. gave me a bunch of 1s.  If there was a way to total those up without performing a loop in my script, that could also work)

Comment: Have you tried:

`select field_a, count(*)
from table_a
WHERE property_a = 1
AND property_b = 2;
group by field_a`

?

Comment: is it mysql or oracle db? is it stored proc or you're sending queries from any programming language?

Comment: Can't you ascertain the count from the number of records returned by the first query?

Comment: @CronosNull post your comment as an answer

Comment: What do you mean by combine them?  Can you show us your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can join each your distinct result with global distinct count:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field_a) as my_records, b.my_count
FROM table_a, 
   (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_a) as my_count FROM table_a 
      WHERE property_a = 1 AND property_b = 2
   ) b
WHERE property_a = 1 AND property_b = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select field_a, count(*)
from table_a 
WHERE property_a = 1 AND property_b = 2
group by field_a
```

?

*Posting as an answer, as suggested by @Bohemian*

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       field_a
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT field_a) OVER ()
FROM table_a
WHERE property_a = 1
AND property_b = 2;
```